# How can I add put inputs into a column? I have a ref down below of what I am trying to do

Tags: angular

```
<mat-form-field appearance="standard">
    <mat-label>Name *</mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="currentUser.username">
</mat-form-field>

 <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
    <mat-label>Email *</mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="currentUser.email">
</mat-form-field>

 <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
    <mat-label>Steamhex *</mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="currentUser.steamhex">
</mat-form-field>
```

[picture of what I am trying to do with my project thank u in advance:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zegry.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly.
Style the parent element of the mat-form-field(s) with:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

That should hopefully do it